# How do I perform an operation iteratively on a python list/array whithout a for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, list, iteration

Is it possible to perform the following operation on the first two elements of the list, storing the result and then performing the next operation on the previous result and the next item in the list for all items in the list without a for loop? Here F(x) is an arbitrarily defined function. 
This is the working code with a for loop:

```
list   = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
result = F(a,b)

for i in range(2,len(list)):
    result = F(result,list[i])

print(result)
```

Thank you very much in advance, the best answer gets a pancake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a reduce function to do this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reduce-in-python/

```py
# importing functools for reduce() 
import functools 

# initializing list 
lis = [ 1 , 3, 5, 6, 2, ] 

# using reduce to compute sum of list 
print ("The sum of the list elements is : ",end="") 
print (functools.reduce(lambda a,b : a+b,lis))
```

For your example

```py
import functools 
list   = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
def F(a,b):
  return a + b #or whatever

result = functools.reduce(F, list)

print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer was perfect. 
Here have a pancake : +1 pancake

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a [reduction](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html?highlight=reduce#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

result = reduce(F, list)
```

`reduce` applies a function to an accumulator (`result`), along with each element of a list. In the first iteration though, if you don't specify an initial accumulator, it will use the initial element as the accumulator.

Answer (score 0):

you can write the funcction yourself:

```
def split_and_compute(_list):
    if len(_list) > 2:
        return myother_fun(_list[0:2]) + split_and_compute(_list[2:])
    else:
        return myother_fun(_list)

def myother_fun(_list):
    return _list[0] + _list[1]
```

Note the + in return myother_fun(_list[0:2]) + split_and_compute(_list[2:]) should be whatever acumulator you have, depending on what data you are dealing with, also this dealswith 2 elements in a very hacky way, can put some guards in there

Comment: The use of `+` here is a really bad idea. This is going to create *many* temporary lists, which will waste space and time.

Comment: python does not have tail recurssion anyway, dont see the problem

Comment: I didn't mention TCO. Every use of `+` will create a copy. And on top of that, every use of slicing will create *another* copy. `myother_fun(_list[0:2]) + split_and_compute(_list[2:])` will create 3 (if I'm counting right) copies of `_list`, *per iteration*.

Comment: what is the problem with that? Obviously he should be using the for loop, reduce is probably going away and its use in python is discouraged, whole point is to show him how it is done, instead of an obscure reduce function, if you want to say that this is inefficient, yes it is, same way could tell him to use scala or haskell to do this things but that is not the question.